# MySQL Getting most occurring Member from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table that stores each and every time someone does something (let's say jumps)

The table has a JumpNumber (auto-increments each time there's an insert, so there's one for every jump rather than this being a total). It also records the member who jumped as MemberID, and the time they jumped at.

I would like to make a query that finds the most occurring member then gives their ID and every time at which they've ever jumped.

However, if there's 2 or more members with the most jumps (so a tie) it should still display each of them, with their jump times.

So I couldn't just do a descending order and limit to 1. I'm also confused as to how I should find the most reoccurring member, I'm guessing a COUNT but not 100% sure how.

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: SELECT MemberId, JumpTime FROM Jumps GROUP BY MemberID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be something like:

```
SELECT USER_ID
  FROM YOURTABLE A
 WHERE JUMPS = (SELECT MAX(JUMPS)
                  FROM YOURTABLE B)
```

This will return all USER_ID with the most Jumps, then you can select all records where the selectes user(s) made something

Comment: Hmm, I want it to actually calculate how many times that member occured in the table and use that as the amount of times jumped, rather than looking at whatever the JumpNumber has incremented to because I want *that* members amount of jumps, not all the jumps that have ever happened.

This is a strange way of doing it, I know, but I want to understand how to it this way

Comment: something like :
select count(*) as jumps_count from members group by id having jumpscount = (select max(jumpscount) from members)

Answer (score 0):

If you store jumps, use variant by Xavjer

If you not store jumps, first you have find max count

```
  select user_id, count(*) as c from TABLE group by user_id order by c desc limit 1
```

After that you have do same grouping again and select all user_id with that count and left join original table for other fields.

```
select A.* from ( 
  select user_id from 
   (select user_id, count(*) as c from TABLE group by user_id) as tempB
   ) as tempC where tempC.c=(
      select  count(*) as c from TABLE group by user_id order by c desc limit 1

                             )
   ) as join_table1
 LEFT JOIN TABLE as  A  on A.user_id=join_table1;
```